# Keep position same for first element in every row inside a Grid when screen size changes

Tags: css, css-grid

> This is what it looks like in fullscreen there is perfect distance between first element in grid
> and the navigation bar.
> [image]

> This is what it looks like when the screen width gets smaller, the first element goes "under" the navigation bar, i want it to keep the distance to it even if screen width gets smaller, eventually when the viewport becomes too small to display all 3 on same row i use media queries to change the grid layout.
> [image]
> .Projects is the class used for the grid

```
 .Projects {
  margin-top: 300px;
  display: grid;
   list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20%;
  margin-left: 10%;
 }
 // this is styling for the individual elements (1, 2 ,3 ) 
.ProjectsShowcase {
 text-align: center;
 width: 270px;
 height: 40vh;
 }
// and here is a media query that changes the layout.
 @media only screen and (max-width: 1630px) {
  .Projects {
   margin-top: 300px;
   display: grid;
   list-style: none;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
   gap: 20%;
   margin-left: 10%;
  }
```

> i have tried adding margin to the left to .Project:first-child but that didn't work

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Why don't you add a padding to that grey area and then make the grid inside with 100% of the remaining space?

Comment: Might be better to change the vertical menu from fixed/absolute position to static position and let it participate in a grid layout. body {display: grid; grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;}